# Search for a match within a collection with elasticsearch & NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm really new to elasticsearch and NEST, so sorry for the basic question.
I'm trying to find out how i can search for all documents that have a match in a collection property.

My elastic document object looks something like this :

```
[ElasticType(Name="my_document")]
public class MyDocument
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long[] TagIds { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know how i search for documents that their `TagIds` property have a certain number in them.

I would like to do something like this :

```
elasticClient.Search<MyDocument>(x =>
        x.Query(s => s.Terms(z => z.TagIds.Contains(searchVal))));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, the answer is really simple, I just didn't fully understand the documentation when i read it.

The query I was looking for is :

```
elasticClient.Search<MyDocument>(x => x.Query(s => s.Term(z => z.TagIds, tagIdStringToSearch)));
```

Note : I am using `Term()` and not `Terms()`. The second parameter is a string of the tagId i'm looking for inside the collection. (This could be an int as well, in my case it's a long, so i search by strings)

Leaving this question up so it might help someone else sometime... :)